# Usage of "wieder"

Tags: meaning

I encountered the following passage:

> Der Kölner Dom grüßt die Besucher schon von weitem mit seinen beiden fast 158 Metern hohen Türmen und nur wenige verlassen die Dom-Stadt **wieder** ohne wenigstens kurz diese Kirche besucht zu haben.

I understand the passage (after *und*) as *only few leave the dome-city without, at least for a short time, visiting the church*, but am not quite sure what role the bolded *wieder* plays in the sentence.

I am aware that *wieder* can mean something other than *again*. My (non-English) dictionary lists *in contrast, on the other hand*, but still can not see how it fits here. So what does this *wieder* mean? Also would removing it change the meaning/nuance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the meaning here is given in [definition 1d in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wieder#d-1-1-4). It means the action returns something to its previous or normal state or location, and be might translated as "back". DWDS gives the example

> *er legte das Buch **wieder** an die richtige Stelle* -- "he put the book **back** in its (proper) place" [translation per Google translate but I added "proper"]

Another example:

> *Schalte das Licht **wieder** aus.* -- "Turn the light **back** off."

From the usage examples I've seen, German sometimes uses *wieder* when English would leave out any adverb since the "return" is implied. Or you might use a different verb such as "restore" or "return" in English to convey this meaning, for example "he **returned** the book to its (proper) place" in the example above. Here's an example from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ausgleichsmandat) (via Wortschatz Leipzig):

> *Dadurch soll das Kräfteverhältnis annähernd wieder hergestellt werden.* -- "This is intended to restore the balance of power approximately."

In your example, I think the "return" sense is implied by context; the visitors/tourists leave (*verlassen*) the city so we assume they're going home. So the *wieder* does really need to be translated into English. But you could include it by using "return (home)" instead of "leave" as the verb. The combination "leave back home" is awkward (at best) in English, but it might be phrased as "go back home" instead.

Comment: Indeed, the "wieder" distinguishes between people that have always lived there and people that only visit the city. Without it, the sentence would apply to both groups. It's basically the same as the "re-" in "return", so "return" hits the spot here.

Comment: Isn't "to leave again" used in the same way in English too?

Comment: @DonHolgo: To be honest I'm not very clear on that myself. Wiktionary (def 5) has the "The South will rise again," and similar examples, I think it depends on the situation, "When the visitors leave again ..." would cause me to wonder when they left before. So while German and English may have some overlap on this, I believe there is a difference in usage.

Comment: @RDBury People seemed to agree here that it's perhaps not technically correct, but idiomatic: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274039/leave-again-is-it-correct-to-add-again

Comment: "*they return back home*" works better than "*leave back home*"

Comment: @DonHolgo: Yes, in the ELL example it's correct to use "again" with "leave", but it still seems to depend on the situation. It's probably off-topic to speculate when it works for English, but it doesn't word all the time. It looks like German is more consistent.